# Avatar resize and delete

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to resize avatar but it's don't work.
I'm using intervention/image package.
Avatar stores but its stores in original sizes and when i update avatar old avatar is not deleting don't know why (
so what's i'm doing wrong?

```
   public function avatarUpdate(Request $r)
    {
        Storage::delete('users'.'/'.Auth::user()->avatar); 
        if ($r->hasFile('avatar')) {
            $thumbnailImage = Image::make($r->avatar);
            $filename = $thumbnailImage->resize(50, 50);
            $filename = $r->avatar->getClientOriginalName();
            $r->avatar->storeAs('users', $filename, 'public');
            $url = 'users/';
            User::where('id', Auth::id())->update([
                'avatar' => $url . $filename
            ]);
        } 
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you are saving the uploaded file, not the file you are creating via intervention ... you are never doing anything with `$thumbnailImage`

Answer (score 1):

I think we need here more context. But i assume that

```
$r->avatar->storeAs('users', $filename, 'public');
```

stores the file into public folder while

```
  Storage::delete('users'.'/'.Auth::user()->avatar);
```

tries to find the image path within private storage.

Try this out

```
Storage::disk('public')->delete('users/'.Auth::user()->avatar);
```

maybe this will work

Comment: Delete still don't works. ( what about resize?

Comment: @Vaskontrop if you look at the basic example of  intervention/image package i says $img->save 

i dont see that you call  $thumbnailImage->save anywhere, the Image class cannot save the resized image if you dont tell him to do so